# Techniques in supporting different android screen sizes and densities

Tags: android, screen, responsive

I am creating an android app and I want to be able to support as many android devices as possible that use Android 4.4 and above.
The screen sizes that I want to support are:

- Normal
- Large
- xLarge

I have created different dimens.xml files for each size.
My first question is, the numbers that I put in each dimens.xml file should be based on the minimum dimension of each category?
For example: for normal I should design the layout in a device with dimension 470dp x 320dp, for large a device with dimensions 640dp x 480dp and for xlarge a device with dimensions 960dp x 720dp ?

My second questions is, let's say that we have our base dimension files for normal, large and xlarge, how many more dimension xml files should I create in order to support different densities too. Also do devices with Android 4.4 and above support all densities or are some excluded? (for example LDPI)

Now let's say that I exclude the LDPI density, should I make each density for each size or if I make one MDPI for each screen size and one HDPI for each screen size everything will "look" the way I want them, even in devices with XXXHDPI density?

One last thing, if you can recommend any devices to make my "base" layout that would be great.

Comment: its better to use svg images here.

Comment: @Saveen I am not referring to images sizes. I am mostly talking about margin, widths, heights, paddings etc

Comment: yes that we can handle wait i'm giving answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can handle size of different resolutions by this,

create different types of values folder.Create these folder inside res.

values-hdpi

values-xhdpi

values-xxhdpi

values-xxxhdpi

and dimens.xml create accordingly for different resolutions.Use all padding and margin from here.

This is way to handle different resolutions for different sizes.

for more info see the below [image].

for more [details](https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp) take a look from my project base structure

Thanks

Comment: So you suggest that I don't use values-normal, values-large and values-xlarge and use only dpi value folders?

Comment: yes right this is best way to handle different sizes

Comment: try with this if you still get any problem then let me know

Comment: I will give it a try and I will let you know

Comment: you need to manually add different sizes of dimens remember it with same name in four folders

Comment: take a look from my project base https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp

Comment: I tried your solution and the problem I am encountering is when I test my app in a 9.6'' tablet (800x1280) that has MDPI density and in a 7'' tablet (600x1024) that has also MDPI density they choose the same dimens file. In the 9.6'' everything looks great but in the 7'' everything is too big.

Comment: You need  to add dimens folder as well for 7 inch tablet

Comment: So I have to create folders with a combination of densities and smallest widths? For 10'': values-sw720-mdpi For 7'': values-sw480-mdpi ?

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)